# VBScript Writing to Server Text File

Tags: vbscript

I have created a VBScript which pulls the service tag, username, and computer name from a computer. What I need to do now is compile this information in a text document.

How it's set up is as follows:

We have an Active Directory Server, with a folder for login scripts. I have created a batch file to run this .vbs script, and the script works well so far. What I now need is for a file on the AD server, called "logging.txt", to be populated with the information that is created with the .vbs script.

This is the script I have so far:

```
'Get Dell Service Tag Info
set ProSet = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_BIOS")
Set ProSet1 = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_SystemEnclosure")
For each Pro in ProSet
  For each Pro1 in ProSet1
   ServiceTag=Pro.SerialNumber
    wscript.echo ServiceTag
    exit for
  Next
  exit for
Next

'get username and computername, could also be asked in a batch
Set oShell     = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oShellEnv  = oShell.Environment("Process")
sComputerName  = oShellEnv("ComputerName")
sUsername      = oShellEnv("username")
wscript.echo sComputerName & " " & sUsername
```

Thank you very much in advance!

This is what I've tried so far:

```
sub log (user, computer)
  dim fs,f
  set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  set f=fs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath(".\logging.csv"),8,true)
  f.WriteLine now & "," & user & "," & computer
  f.Close:set f=Nothing
  set fs=Nothing
end sub
```

Comment: Besides the code that is working, what have you tried and determined didn't work, you have to at least show us what you tried.

Comment: @Ramhound I've tried writing this so far: 
`sub log (user, computer)
  dim fs,f
  set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  set f=fs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath(".\logging.csv"),8,true)
  f.WriteLine now & "," & user & "," & computer
  f.Close:set f=Nothing
  set fs=Nothing
end sub`

Comment: If you're still getting that access denied error the account you are running the script under doesn't have write permissions for the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel as though you're leaving something out.. this is how to write a text file in VBS.

```
dim filesys, filetxt, getname, path
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filetxt = filesys.CreateTextFile("c:\somefile.txt", True)
path = filesys.GetAbsolutePathName("c:\somefile.txt")
getname = filesys.GetFileName(path)
filetxt.WriteLine("Your text goes here.")
filetxt.Close
If filesys.FileExists(path) Then
   Response.Write ("Your file, '" & getname & "', has been created.")
End If
```

Comment: I'm getting a "Permission Denied" - 800A0046 Error Message

Comment: Obviously the account running the script needs write access to the folder.

Comment: If you're using windows vista or 7, chances are you do not have permission to write files in the root of the drive.  Consider also that it is not considered "polite" for an installed program to make files outside of its working directories unless directed to do so specifically by the user.  Consider using a location in the user's temp folder or application data folder instead.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easiest to save the information to a local text file and upload it with the command line ftp utility from the batch script that calls your script rather than trying to invent another wheel and do it in vbscript.

You can list the command line options of ftp with:

```
ftp /?
```

I recommend setting up something like this:

```
ftp -s:control.txt
```

control.txt would contain something like:

```
open [hostname or address]
[username]
[password]
cd [remote directory name]
put logging.txt
disconnect
bye
```

Comment: This will not work, because I will eventually have to deploy this to 700 end users.

Comment: Can you call the command line ftp client from VB then?  It is a windows component and is present on every windows system, probably as far back as windows 95 and older.

Comment: Even still, once all this happened I would then have to manually parse the information to another file.

Comment: Parsing is the process of reading, not writing.  You will find that it would be considerably more work to write an implementation of FTP than it would to write the file, which should take about 5 or 6 lines.  What is the format of the file?